# How will I go about parsing this information from html source

Tags: php, html, split, web-scraping

I am trying to parse some html code in a table.

I have organized the code as good as I could, so you can understand what I am trying to do.
Code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/q83Dk82Q

From each 'tr' class "odd" and "even" I want to get the following information:

```
<a title="Download torrent file" href="link here.." class="idownload icon16"
```

And the torrent name:

```
  <a href="/grand-theft-auto-v-ps3-duplex-t7864825.html" class="normalgrey font12px plain bold">
        <strong class="red">
          Grand
        </strong>

        <strong class="red">
          Theft
        </strong>

        <strong class="red">
          Auto
        </strong>

        <strong class="red">
          V
        </strong>
        PS3-DUPLEX
      </a>
```

As you can see, the torrent name have on some of the words a ' strong class="red" ' I want to be able to remove those and get the full torrent name.

---

So far I have this code where I'll get the html content from the URL.

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider",
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
);

$ch      = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$err     = curl_errno( $ch );
$errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
$header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

$header['errno']   = $err;
$header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
$header['content'] = $content;
return $header;
}

$data =  get_web_page('http://kickass.to/usearch/grand%20theft%20auto%20v%20category:ps3/');
print_r(htmlspecialchars($data['content']));
```

If anyone could help me with this it would be highly appreciated! Thanks ;)

Comment: Use a [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), and you could consider learning XPATH

Comment: Okay thank you, I will try to learn DOM parser or XPATH!

Answer (score 0):

[DOMxpath] can help you find the content of element[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

```
<?php
    $html = '<a href="/grand-theft-auto-v-ps3-duplex-t7864825.html" class="normalgrey font12px plain bold">
        <strong class="red">
          Grand
        </strong>

        <strong class="red">
          Theft
        </strong>

        <strong class="red">
          Auto
        </strong>

        <strong class="red">
          V
        </strong>
        PS3-DUPLEX
      </a>';
    echo getName($html);
    function getName($html){
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
        $entries = $xpath->query('//a');
        echo $entries->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to get all of them?

Comment: DOM->query("tr") and then foreach every tr , query a. It will be okay

Comment: Can you show me how that will look with $data as source. Sorry, but I'm no expert with xpath yet.